# How to get a network of different IP addresses on IPv6?

Tags: networking, ip, webserver, ipv6, tcpip

Does anyone know if it is possible to get a network of different IP addresses on IPv6 (not sure if they have it in my area?). What I'm thinking is maybe I could have a little network like at work now they have loads of 'network addresses' and I could do things with them. Does anyone know how I would go about trying to set up an IPv6 network with lots of my own addresses? Is it to do with putting a slash then a number after an IP address?

Comment: I think you will have to edit this question. I simply cannot figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: I actually kind of get it, though I suppose the question could be tightened up a bit

Comment: yes, I try my best

Answer (score 0):

There's two options - both involving an ipv6 tunnel broker. The first option's what you're asking about, the second's an alternative. In any case a proper ipv6 capable router is a VERY good idea.

For a network with a known, globally routable endpoint, you can get a *single* tunnel with a range of ip addresses to a router that has a tunnel broker client, or set up a tunnel per client. The former is better if you have a fair amount of skill, the latter is better if you're just experimenting.

Its a bit involved - you need a ipv6 tunnel, and *preferably* a router that is ipv6 enabled - [Its possible to set this up 'manually' on an ipv6 system](http://tomicki.net/ipv6.router.php), but getting a router that supports it is the smart option. [My asus supports it on HE](https://forums.he.net/index.php?topic=2680.0) and its probably a great idea to check on their forums to see if your router supports it.

That said ipv6 addresses from a tunnel broker a *typically* globally routable, and they don't actually need to be on the same subnet. The 'local' lan setup you'd find on the typical ipv4 system is a consequence of NAT.

If you want a /48, go with hurricane electric, set it up on a supported router and its dead simple.

However, I went with the other option before I got native ipv6 and used [gogonet](http://www.gogo6.com/) on a *laptop* - their client supported udpv6 and didn't need me to open up ports, or any fancy stuff. You can run this per laptop.

Finally, remembering ipv6 addresses is a *pain*. If you have a domain, set up AAAA addresses so you don't need to remember them.

Finally, once you do switch to ipv6, if you need to type them in on a browser, the address is inside square brackets, and the colons in ipv6 are the same as the dots in a  ipv4 address. The slash and the number refers to the [size of the subnet](http://www.potato-people.com/blog/2009/02/ipv6-subnet-size-reference-table/) with a /48 having up to 1,208,925,819,614,629,174,706,176 ip addresses. That should be good for a fairly large network.